# Joomla 3 - search phpMyAdmin

Tags: joomla

I'm new in Joomla and I have a database in phpMyAdmin and a stored table in it. I want to create a search in my Joomla site in order to search the database and present some results in my page. Also I want my search to make indexing in the stored data. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Make you would like to search for "How to make a search plugin" - don't get intimidated by the title, it's what you need to create for indexing and allowing Joomla to include your custom data in its search results.

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos I found this: http://docs.joomla.org/J3.1:Creating_a_search_plugin. Thanks!